# Get XMLGregorianCalendar date in EST time Zone

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

I am using `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));` to get the time zone EST and it is working fine to me. But sometimes I am getting time zone EDT when no one called this method in my project because of the default JVM time zone.

```
public getTimeInEST(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    String newTime = formatter.format(date.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        newDate = formatter.parse(newTime);
        System.out.println("ESTDate : " + newDate)
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way where I get XMLGregorianCalendar date in EST time zone without using `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))`?

Comment: You don't need to set both the default timezone and call `formatter.setTimeZone`, surely?

Comment: I am getting EST time without any error but I don't want to use  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")); to get EST time.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you should just pass the time zone to `toGregorianCalendar`. I'd also strongly recommend using full time zone IDs rather than abbreviations - after all, I suspect you really want Eastern time (EST and EDT) rather than just EST.

Also, there's no need to format a string value and then parse it - you can just use `Calendar.getTime()`:

```
// Possibly...
public Date toDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    Calendar calendar = date.toGregorianCalendar(zone, Locale.US, null);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Note that a `Date` value doesn't *have* a time zone - it's just an instant in time. The return value of `Date.toString()` is misleading in that it always uses the system default time zone, but there's no such thing as "a `Date` in the Eastern time zone".

I've included the "possible" in the comment as it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. This code is only useful if the `XMLGregorianCalendar` specifies the date/time but no time zone, and you want to assume it actually represents a value in the Eastern time zone, and convert that to an instant in time. *Is* that what you want?

Comment: I am getting timeZone in IST after using above code.

Comment: I am passing XMLGregorianCalendar date and I want EST Timezone without using TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))

Comment: @UserJHa: What *exactly* do you mean by "I want EST time zone" and what *exactly* do you mean by "I am getting timeZone in IST"? Read the middle paragraph carefully - if you've got a `java.util.Date` value, that *just* represents a point in time. It doesn't have a time zone.